# Shell script - Write column-wise to csv

Tags: shell, csv

When I use the commands below in a shell script, it writes 1, 2, and 3 in the first three cells of the first row.

```
values=1,2,3
echo $values | tee test.csv
```

I am wondering how we can instead create a csv file with the numbers written vertically in the first column.

Comment: try something like `values = 1\
2\
3` (enter seperated after every \ char)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $value | sed "s/,/\n/g" | tee test.csv
```

Adding a simple sed command to replace commas with the newline character should do the work. Sed is substituting all occurrences of , with \n i.e. new line character.